# PyCharm: Moving a project into a sister folder

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have recently moved the folder that an existing PyCharm project is in.  My pipeline of scripts now are having issues identifying the other scripts as modules.  The error code I receive is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/donaldvetal/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-    
packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-4-84c563cce2e6>", line 4, in <module>
import performTopicAnalysis as ta
ImportError: No module named performTopicAnalysis
```

In this case I am calling the perfromTopicAnalysis.py file as an import in my other file called dt_company.py.  Also note these scripts are located in the same directory.  All of these scripts are located in an app folder of a django project.

Why is this happening and what might be a good solution to this?  Thank you!

EDIT:

Bottom-line solution: In init.py file add sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('./')) OR sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(__file__)). Guy below has a better explanation.

Comment: "I have recently moved the folder an existing PyCharm project is in." Please correct your sentence, what is it that you exactly did?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your libraries folder is not on the syspath. Pycharm inserts the root folder of your project in the syspath, put that does not add the subfolders directly. If you want to call any module inside the  folder, you'd have to the module.submodule notation on import. Ex:

Before:

```
/
main.py
file1.py
file2.py
```

from main.py, use `import file1`

After:

```
/
main.py
module/
      __init__.py
      file1.py  
      file2.py
```

from main.py, use import module.file1

If between file1 and file2 they called themselves and now it is not working, remember that the directory python is running from (probably the root) is the one that he is going to look for libraries.

One solution would be to add the `module` path to the syspath as well.

On `__init__.py`

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

See if that solves the problem

Comment: It initially solved the problem but a day later for some reason I was getting 'NameError: name '__file__' is not defined'.  Altered to state sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('./')). Works now.